# Extract integers in a string python re.findall

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the below code which is working fine but when my string is "`hello I am in 12th grade but i am 230 years old`", I am getting `12, 230` but I want `12230` as one integer. How do I achieve that?

```
import re

def main():
    str1 = 'ABCD12'
    str1 = input("Enter a String: ")
    str1 = "3158 reviews"
    person = re.findall('\d+', str1)
    if person:
        print(person)
    else:
        print("0")

main()
```

Comment: You can just strip all non-numerics? `person = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', str1)`

Comment: You should accept the answer that was most helpful to you

Answer (score 5):

Using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), you can join multiple strings into one string:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', "hello I am in 12th grade but i am 230 years old")
['12', '230']
>>> ''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', "hello I am in 12th grade but i am 230 years old"))
'12230'
```

BTW, instead of using regular expression, you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, "hello I am in 12th grade but i am 230 years old"))
'12230'
```

---

**UPDATE**

As Donkey Kong commented, you can also use `re.sub` to remove non-digit characters:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\D+', '', "hello I am in 12th grade but i am 230 years old")
'12230'
```

But, with this you can't check whether there was digit or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you intended to do with manually assigning values to `str1` after taking user input to it.

```
import re

def main():
    str1 = input("Enter a String: ")
    person = re.findall('\d+', str1)
    print(''.join(person) if person else '0')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla version:

```
def main():
    str1 = 'ABCD12'
    str1 = input("Enter a String: ")
    str1 = "3158 reviews"
    person = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str1))
    if person:
        print(person)
    else:
        print("0")

main()
```